# HTTP 400 on payout

Tags: python, http, paypal

I've been trying to build Paypal cash out system for my website, I viewed countless Paypal API pages and interpreted all the examples to Python:

```
import requests
import string
import random
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

class makePayment(object):
    def __init__(self, paypal_email, subject, amount, note, clientid, secret):
        self.access_token = self.obtain_access_token(clientid, secret) # Successfully obtained access token
        self.headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer {0}".format(self.access_token)}
        self.sender_batch_id = self.generate_sender_batch_id() # Randomly generated sender_batch_id in base36 ([A-Z] and [1-9])
        self.payout_form = self.create_payout_form(self.sender_batch_id, paypal_email, subject, amount, note) # Not encoded in JSON, just normal HTML form
        self.response = requests.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts",
                                      data=self.payout_json,
                                      headers=self.headers)

    def httpResponse(self):
        return self.response

    @staticmethod
    def obtain_access_token(clientid, secret):
        headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Language": "en_US"}
        response = requests.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
                                 auth=HTTPBasicAuth(clientid, secret),
                                 data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"},
                                 headers=headers)
        return dict(response.json()).get("access_token")

    @staticmethod
    def generate_sender_batch_id():
        base36 = str(string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase)
        return "".join([random.choice(base36) for char in range(1, 9)])

    @staticmethod
    def create_payout_form(sender_batch_id, paypal_email, subject, amount, note):
        payout_dict = {
            'sender_batch_header': {
                    'sender_batch_id': sender_batch_id,
                    'email_subject': subject,
            },
            'items': [{
                'recipient_type': 'EMAIL',
                'amount': {
                    'value': amount,
                    'currency': 'USD'
                },
                'receiver': paypal_email,
                'note': note,
                'sender_item_id': '${0} item'.format(amount),
            }]
        }
        return payout_dict
```

[token generator](https://www.paypal.com/tc/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-ts2128), [payout example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch#payouts_create)

I get http error 400 (bad request), before that i've tried encoding data in json and got http error 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY), maybe json encoding was the proper method?

Take in note that `sender_batch_id` is randomly generated, since i don't know any other method to obtain it.

What am i doing incorrectly? Is there a possibility that i'm missing some parameters? I think there's some problem with the authentication header. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

most of the times - POST requests that are from type "application/json" need to be sent in a json format :

```
 response = requests.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
                             auth=HTTPBasicAuth(clientid, secret),
                             json={"grant_type": "client_credentials"},
                             headers=headers)
```

i used

```
json
```

instead of

```
data
```

in your POST request

Comment: I can successfully obtain access token, but i can't seem to make payment, even if i try json argument, it returns http 400. If i try to encode dict to json and then pass it as json argument, it returns HTTP 422.

Comment: try inspect actual transaction on Paypal and see that your parameters match, or read the API more carefully  and see if you miss something

Comment: Now i tried to change `sender_item_id` to `sender_batch_id` and then pass json encoded dict in requests json argument but response still remains 422. I think i didn't miss any parameter.